# How to implement HorizontalScrollView inside listview with CursorAdapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, android-cursoradapter, horizontalscrollview

I'm trying to implement `HorizontalScrollView` on multiple rows of listview with custom `CursorAdapter`.

I had a module which allows to select multiple images at a time and insert their paths in database with a unique timestamp tag. Timestamp tag is same for all images which are selected at once, because i'm trying to put these images in horizontal scrollview based on these tags.

I want to show one group of images with same timestamp tag in one row, another group in second row and so on.

My row XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hsvImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

`newView()`

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_single_chat,
                parent, false);

    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    holder.llParent = (LinearLayout) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.llParent);
    holder.hsvImg = (HorizontalScrollView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.hsvImage);
    holder.llImg = (LinearLayout) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.llImage);
    return viewLayout;
}
```

**1st approach in bindView():**

At first, i simply add my programmatic imageviews to `holder.llImg`. It adds one image in one simple row that doesn't show horizontal scrollview at all :

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor){

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    String imagePath = cursor.getString(indexImagePath);

    ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
    iv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(450, 450));
    iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);

    iv.setImageBitmap(bm);

    //Add views to linear layout
    holder.llImg.addView(iv);
}
```

**2nd approach in bindView():**

I tried to group images based on imageTags, by comparing current tag with next one and if mismatch found, create new linear layout instance with findViewById() to switch to next row:

In following case `llImg` is a `LinearLayout` instance variable and `tagThis` & `tagPrev` are String instance variables.

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor){

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    String imagePath = cursor.getString(indexImagePath);

    String imageTag = cursor.getString(indexImageTag);

    if (imageTag != null) {

        if (llImg == null) {

            //Create new linear layout
            llImg = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llImage);
        }

        //Check if cursor position is greater than 0
        if (cursor.getPosition() < cursor.getCount() - 1) {

            //get current image tag
            tagThis = cursor.getString(indexImageTag);

            //get next record's image tag
            cursor.moveToPosition(cursor.getPosition() + 1);
            tagPrev = cursor.getString(indexImageTag);
        }
        //Return cursor to original position
        cursor.moveToPosition(cursor.getPosition());

        //compare current and next record's image tag
        if ((tagThis != null) && (!tagThis.equals(tagPrev))) {

            //Create new linear layout
            llImg = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llImage);
        }

        ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(450, 450));
        iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);

        iv.setImageBitmap(bm);

        //Add views to linear layout
        llImg.addView(iv);
    }
}
```

It turns out a bit successful but later found out that `findViewById()` does not return new instance of `linear layout`, so on some points it does not switch to next row. And also some times views get messed up in each other on scrolling - that old recycling issue.

**3rd approach in bindView():**

At third, when 1st imageTag hits, i get all the rows from table of that imageTag with `WHERE` query and add all results in `linear layout`. But again fail to switch to next row on some points.:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor){

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    String imagePath = cursor.getString(indexImagePath);

    String imageTag = cursor.getString(indexImageTag);

    if (imageTag != null) {

        //Create new linear layout
        llImg = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llImage);

        LocalStoreDB localDB = new LocalStoreDB(context);
        localDB.openDB();

        //Get all rows of imageTag with where query
        Cursor cr = localDB.selectTagData(imageTag);
        while (cr.moveToNext()) {

            String imagePath2 = cr.getString(indexFilePath);

            ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
            iv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(450, 450));
            iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath2);

            iv.setImageBitmap(bm);

            //Add views to linear layout
            llImg.addView(iv);
        }

        localDB.closeDB();
    }
}
```

I tried these 3 approaches, and unable to switch to next `listview` row with `linear layout` which has horizontal orientation.

What is the correct way to accomplish this ?

Comment: you should be used horizontally listview

Comment: actually this is customized listview with many other views which requires vertical listview orientation. i put only necessary code to avoid confusion.

Comment: share screenshot, i am not understand...